# What game is this sound track from?

Tags: game-identification

I'm intrigued by how mysterious this song sounds. Must be an awesome game. Does anyone know what game this sound track comes from?

#### Edit

The video is a collage of various NES games, none of which has the sound track playing in the background.

Comment: It's probably not Nintendo. They'd have filed a C&D by now.

Comment: I've commented on the video, hopefully the person who made it replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a royalty free music piece by TeknoAxe (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtgf00GvfFQVsYBA7V7RwUw).  Not from any game.

This was discovered due to @Robotnik asking as a comment on the video you linked.